# How to remove this '...' characters from code in VS?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

When I tried press the `CTRL+D+E` keys combination, I typed a wrong combination that turns my code in VS in this:

[image]

what's the purpose of this characters and how do I remove them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are space charactes.

You pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd> (Edit, Advanced, Show White Space)

Comment: Ctrl + R, Ctrl + W also toggles it.

Answer (score 2):

The dots denote whitespace characters. Press Ctrl+R, Ctrl+W to hide them.